# How to solve next button in js gallery

Tags: javascript, function, gallery

I have some troubles with image gallery in JavaScript. Anything works, but after few operations processing to load next image takes too long. 
Here is a code:

```
function showbox(x)
{
  document.getElementById("box").style.visibility = "visible";
  for(i=1; i<5; i++){
    document.getElementById("d"+i).innerHTML="&#9675;";
  }
  if (x==1){
    document.getElementById("myImg").src = "img1.gif"; 
    document.getElementById("d"+x).innerHTML="&#9679;";
    $('#rightbutton').click(function() { showbox(x+1); });
    $('#leftbutton).click(function() { showbox(x-1); });
    return 0;
  } else if (x==2){
    document.getElementById("myImg").src = "img2.gif"; 
    document.getElementById("d"+x).innerHTML="&#9679;";
    $('#rightbutton').click(function() { showbox(x+1); });
    $('#leftutton').click(function() { showbox(x-1); });
    return 0;
  }
  E.t.c


  function nextimg(y){
    showbox(y);
  }

  function prvimg(y){
    showbox(y);
  }
```

Comment: Why does `showbox` return `0` no matter the outcome of the `if` statement?  Just have the `return 0` line after the `if`. Also, there is no need to have the two `nextimg` and `prvimg` functions, given that they both do the same thing. Make sure you get your DOM references that you know you will need, as soon as the DOM is ready and not at the last moment when you need them and then again the next time - store them in a variable.

Comment: You should show the corresponding HTML as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time `showbox` is called, you set up new `click` event handlers for your `#rightbutton` and `#leftbutton` elements without removing the previous ones. So, the more you click those buttons, the more event handlers they get, which causes more events and so on. Just assign the event handlers once, at document load.

Additionally, why does `showbox` return `0` no matter the outcome of the `if` statement and given that you never do anything with the return value?  It doesn't appear that you even need that (if you do, just have `return 0` one time after the `if` statement).

Also, there is no need to have the two `nextimg` and `prvimg` functions, given that they both do the same thing, which is just to call `showbox`. Instead of calling those functions, just call `showbox`.

Lastly, make sure you get your DOM references that you know you will need, as soon as the DOM is ready and not at the last moment when you need them and then again the next time - store them in a variable.

Comment: With variables it was even worse, but when I add $('#leftbutton').removeAttr("onclick"); it's ok